# wont do FOR more than once, do the while, but the for not

Tags: javascript, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop

this code,

```
for (a = 0; a < 5;a++){ 
    var namex = document.getElementsByClassName("tooltip_sticky")[a].getAttribute("name",2);
    var n=namex.split("'");
    i = 0;
    while(i < 30) {
    var achou = n[i].indexOf("mission=1");
        if (achou == -1) {
        alert(achou);
        i++;
        }
        else {
            alert("Lol");
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

it have to run first a as 0, than do the while 30 times, return to a, set a to 1, do while more 30, return to a, set to 2, do while 30 times...

but it do the WHILE the first 30 times, and stop, why its not returning to the FOR?

Comment: It is. My guess is that you don't have multiple elements with the `tooltip_sticky` class, so you're getting an error on the second loop iteration when you try to use `getAttribute` on an element that doesn't exist. There's a debugger built into your browser, I suggest using it to single-step through the code and watch what happens.

Comment: look at the js console and see if any error occurs

Comment: Side note: As far as I'm aware, [`getAttribute` only accepts one argument, not two](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-666EE0F9).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, no this inst the problem, i tested it, and if i type number in place of "a", like:

document.getElementsByClassName("tooltip_sticky")[1].getAttribute("name",2);

or

document.getElementsByClassName("tooltip_sticky")[2].getAttribute("name",2);


.... [3] [4] etc..

it return the correct info, that the for dont!!

Comment: @user2582318: The suggestion remains the same: Single-step through the code with the debugger. You'll be able to see where the problem is. **Something** is raising an error (or something you haven't shown is changing the value of `a`). Those are the only reasons it would leave the loop.

Comment: @user2582318: Two other thoughts: 1. This is all within a function, right? and 2. In that function, you **do** declare `a` and `i` somewhere, right? Because if not, you're falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html), and something could be mucking with `a`.

Comment: I think the error is inside the while, precisely here: `n[i].indexOf("mission=1");`. Since `n` is a split by `'` of the name, it is possible that it doesn't have 30 quotes inside of it, and cycling through them would cause an error since if `n[i]` is undefined, `.indexOf` of undefined returns a TypeError. Maybe it would be more safe to keep the while looping *while* `i < n.length`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, i got, you idea of the debug showed me that the indexOf, was unedefined, it do the n.indexOf 30 times, but n doesnt have 30 spaces of array, understand?

=x

Comment: do you know how to say the lenght of the n? i tried using n.lenght, but say "undefined"

Comment: It is **`length`**, not `lenght`

Comment: @LightStyle :O! thx u.u kill me! ;x

Comment: @LightStyle: I just saw your comment above. Let me know if you want me to delete my answer in favor of you reposting that comment as an answer.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, don't worry, I upvoted you and hope you'll get the answer accepted :) I'm not here to get reputation, I'm just glad to help!

Comment: @LightStyle: All the more reason you should be recognized when you do help. :-) But cool.

Answer (score 2):

The fundamental thing here is that there are only two reasons the loop may not continue:

1. Something you haven't shown is changing the value of `a`, or
2. An error is being thrown (this is more likely).

In the latter case, the error can be found in the JavaScript console of your browser.

In either case, single-stepping through the code using the debugger built into your browser can help you find out where that error is.

From the comments, it sounds like `var n=namex.split("'");` isn't necessarily resulting in an array with at least 30 elements. So you need to change your inner loop:

```
var n=namex.split("'");
i = 0;
while(i < n.length) { // <=== Change is here
```

...since otherwise, `n[i]` may be `undefined` and trying to call methods on it will throw an error.

---

FWIW, your `while` loop also wants to be a `for` loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < n.length; ++i) {
    var achou = n[i].indexOf("mission=1");
    if (achou == -1) {
        alert(achou);
    }
    else {
        alert("Lol");
    }
}
```

---

You haven't shown any declaration for `a` or `i` in your code. I assume you *have* declared them somewhere; if not, you're falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).

---

Finally: As far as I'm aware, [`getAttribute` only accepts one argument, not two](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-666EE0F9).

Comment: There was a flagging system for attribute casing in older IEs. "`2 Returns the value exactly as it was set in script or in the source document.`" (Citation from an old Office documentation from year 1999.)